Transistor output voltage measurement does not change with PWM duty cycle
Forgive me if this is a simple question, but why is it that when I read the voltage between (+) of my power source and the drain of my IRF540N MOSFET with a multimeter, the voltage reads as almost constant no matter how the PWM signal at the gate is adjusted. However, when I attach a load, such as an LED, the brightness change can be visually observed as the PWM is adjusted. Its a simple configuration with a 10k pulldown resistor.
Perhaps there is some gaps in my knowledge on transistors, I would really appreciate it if someone could explain why this is happening.

The drain-source capacitance of the MOSFET will be around 1 nF. Your multimeter's input resistance will be around 10 MΩ. That's an RC time constant of 10 ms so, if the PWM frequency is 1 kHz or above, your meter would show a near-enough constant voltage that is equal to your power supply voltage (virtually irrespective of duty cycle).
If you reduced your PWM frequency to around 100 Hz you will start to see a distinct flickering/lowering in the reading of your multimeter.
When you attach a 10 kΩ load, it discharges the drain-source capacitance in about 10 μs and, if your PWM frequency was high-enough (1 MHz or above) you would get the same effect on your multimeter and, it's also likely that the LED would get brighter.
Several assumptions have been made in this answer. All of them based on experience and normality.
